# what does the below shell script mean?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have seen one shell script starting with the below code :-

```
#!/bin/bash

currfoldername=$1
cd $currfoldername
```

can anyone describe what does $1 mean here?

Thanks for your reply!!

Comment: Type `man bash` in your terminal then scroll until you reach *"Positional Parameters"* under the *"PARAMETERS"* section.

Answer (score 2):

$1 means the first argument given while executing the shell script.

Example -

```
# my_script.sh
#!/bin/bash

currfoldername=$1
cd $currfoldername
echo "in $currfoldername"
```

execute  -

```
./my_script.sh my_folder
```

output -

```
 # value of variable currfoldername is my_folder.
 #cd to my_folder
 in my_folder  # echo statement
```

Comment: thanks, but someone told me that here $1 means whenever you call the shell script then that time you will have to pass input over here like current directory/path. Is it right explanation?

Comment: That's just a really poor way of restating what this answer is telling you

Comment: @BimanRoy Well you can also not pass any argument and still this script will run but will show unexpected behavior.